# VS Code Typescript intellisense does not read correctly Typings

Tags: visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I have installed in my Ionic 3 project [pdfjs-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist) from npm and the [typings from DT](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/354cec620daccfa0ad167ba046651fb5fef69e8a/types/pdf), but I do not get the correct intellisense, look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBSdB.jpg

VS Code: 1.12.2
Typescript: 2.3.3

In my typings folder I have:

- Typings

  - Globals

    - pdf

      - index.d.ts

My tsconfig.json says:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

and my dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.2",
        "@ionic-native/core": "3.10.2",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.10.2",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.10.2",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "@types/pdf": "0.0.31",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
        "ionic-angular": "3.3.0",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "pdfjs-dist": "^1.8.428",
        "rxjs": "5.1.1",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.3.0",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.0",
        "typescript": "2.3.3"
    },
```

I have looked other questions here [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224476/vs-code-typings-no-intellisense) this or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737133/typescript-intellisense-with-import-statement-vs-code) and did not find an solution.

**Edit:**
I had added updated my includes with the path to the dt typings `"typings/**/*.d.ts"` and I had this warning while compiling:

> typescript: node_modules/@types/pdf/index.d.ts, line: 51
>               Duplicate string index signature.
>
> L51:   * A unique ID to identify a PDF.  Not guaranteed to be unique.  [jbaldwin: haha what]
>
> L52:   **/

That point me out that the types are not been reading from `typings/**` but from `node_modules/@types/`. I took a look and saw that both `index.d.ts` files are exactly the same so I uninstalled the typings outside node.

After a while of looking into it I have two main theories about my problem.
1. I do not know what I am doing (Very possible)
2. The Typings are wrong and/or Outdated.

I have found a  `PDFJSStatic` interface that contains the "unintellisensed" method in my screen capture that is exported in the typings. If I do something like:

```
import * as PDF_JS  from 'pdfjs-dist';
let pdfjsLib : PDFJSStatic = PDF_JS;
```

I finally get Info about the `getDocument()` method but a lot of other functions get broken.

If I get the PDFJSStatic as an own variable:

```
var PDFJSStatic : PDFJSStatic = pdfjsLib.PDF;
```

The intellisense works but obviously the functions does not exist.

Comment: Are the typings files included under the src directory? Also try updating your `include` to include d.ts files as well. Since you are manually managing typings, you must explicitly include them in the tsconfig project

Comment: Thanks @MattBierner, I have tried that and no success, but something interesting happen. Look at my update.

Comment: Yes, you cannot have both `dt` typings and `@types` typings for a library. Try switching over to using `@types` which is now the recommended way to manage typings files. The intellisense doesn't work automatically in your case because you are using `pdfjs-dist` but have typings installed for  `@types/pdf`. We won't associate the typings from `pdf` with `pdfjs-dist`. Maybe the typings file is out of date/broken?

Comment: @MattBierner thanks again. I have uninstalled the typings from dt and just keep the `@types`. But yes, I think both typings are out of date because for once I get the intellisense for some things like some interfaces but there are functions like `renderTextLayer` that doesn't even exist in the `d.ts` file.